# How to include one VueJS application into another VueJS application

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, components

Hello my fellow programmers,

The issue (a lot simplified in the following case):

- I have a simple vuejs application (let's call it `Child`), doing basically nothing, just a `click` function and that's it.
- I have another vuejs application (let's call it `Parent`), with a blank page.
- What I want to achieve is to **import the Child application into Parent as a component**

Note:

- I have used a `http-server` npm package, in order to host `Child` after it has been built.
- I have tried to import `Child` inside `Parent`, but of course `import` doesn't work with urls.
- The two projects are hosted in two separate repositories and they cannot be under the same repository.

Comment: Why you don't use two component as parent and child? Then you can use child component inside parent component with using slots: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html

Comment: I second the answer of patapity. At least in my perspective, I don't see the need of 2 Vue instances.